# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, web-applications, tiles

I am creating an application using Tiles, Spring and Hibernate.

When when running, it is showing following error:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
```

All the jars are included and mapping is also seeing fine. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: It is showing compilation error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The url looks ok.

Your problem sounds a bit like you are missing some tiles jars. Make sure that a jar containing `tiles-jsp.tld` is added to your projects web `libs` folder.

One jar that contains this file is for example: [`tiles-jsp-2.2.1.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp/2.2.1).

Answer (score 4):

In pom.xml file appended below artifacts and compiled well this time.

```
<!-- Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the whole file with the `taglib` declaration from somewhere else and got the same compilation error. I deleted the file, created a new one and pasted the same contents. Sounds weird but worked! Hope it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem even after having tiles-jsp.2.0.6.jar. So i found the solution by removing the jar manually from the maven dependencies and adding it as an external jar.. It worked, you may also try so..

Answer (score 0):

Adding the tiles dependency in pom.xml of Spring project will help-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```